# Apply blur effect to a bitmap in console application c#

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have a bitmap

```
Bitmap shadow = (Bitmap)finalImage.Clone();
```

I am trying to blur this bitmap. After searching on the internet I found this dll

```
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
```

I have this function now

```
BlurBitmapEffect myBlurEffect = new BlurBitmapEffect();
myBlurEffect.Radius = 10;
myBlurEffect.KernelType = KernelType.Box;
```

anyone knows how to get the image blurred?

Comment: Windows.Media is part of WPF. You will find the docs on MSDN. Note that you will have to include many (5-10 or so) references to your project to make it work.

Comment: can you give me a link to any example?

Comment: No. also: Do not re-post the same question!